# Surrounding elements using JQuery - before() not doing what I want

Tags: jquery, dom

I have some HTML and I am calling each `H1` using `.each()`.  I **WANT** to not only surround the H1's but all the content below it -until the next `H1`- with a div.

If I try something like:

```
$('#presentationcontent h1').each(function (index) {
      $(this).before('<div>');
```

It closes the div for me... I wanted to do something like this:

```
 $('#presentationcontent h1').each(function (index) {
        counter++;
        if (counter == 1) 
        {
            $(this).before('<div class="headingSections" style="border: 1px">');
        }
        else
        {
           $(this).before('</div><div class="headingSections" style="border: 1px">');
        }
```

Hoping that I could set the first `H1` to `<div>` and every other one to close the `<div>` and open a new one... that way ALL THE CONTENT under the `H1` gets included.

Anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making assumptions about your HTML setup, the following would do the trick:

```
$('#presentationcontent h1').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('h1').andSelf().wrapAll('<div/>');
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s2zTN/2/) of it working.

Comment: Jeez!  How exactly does one go about finding out about that!?  Thats awesome and all... but how did you learn that?

Comment: Two things help a lot: [Google](http://www.google.com) and [jQuery Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('#presentationcontent h1').each(function (index) {
    $(this).nextUntil('h1').andSelf().wrapAll('<div/>');
    // ...
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7V2fb/1/